# jQuery.data('abc','xyz') not changing data-abc

Tags: jquery, dom, custom-data-attribute

I have a working function:

```
$('#hints').after(
   '<a href="#" id="hint" class="btn btn-large btn-success" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="Hint 1 Content" data-original-title="Hint 1 Title">Hint 1</a>'
)
```

I am trying to edit `data-content="Hint 1 Content"` with jQuery.

My function is:

```
function loadContent(riddle) {
    $('#hint').data('content','h1 content')
}
```

Then I call `loadContent(RIDDLE)` but this does not change the `data-content` tag in my `<a>` tag.

Comment: Can you replicate in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2):

`data` attributes are mapped to [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset) property of the DOM Element object, your code should work, you can't see it's changed as it is a property not an attribute.

```
$('#hint').data('content','h1 content')
console.log( $('#hint').data('content') ) // 'h1 content'
```

If you want to change the attribute you can use `attr` method instead of `data` method, however, note that jQuery handles `data-*` differently than `dataset` property (*which is not supported in older browsers + IEs*).

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  Possible solution to your problem: Are you creating more than one element with the same `id`?.

Try also this to be more verbose, and use `console.log` to verify:

```
var el = $('<a href="#" id="hint">Hint 1</a>').data('abc', 'xyz');
console.log(el.data('abc'))
$('#hints').after(el)
console.log($("#hint").data('abc'))
```